# Как вывести посты через ajax в wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, null

`Ajax` запросом хочу вывести посты, но функции `the_post()` и `the_content()` возвращают `NULL`.

Файл `function.php`:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_menu', 'get_ajax_menu');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_menu', 'get_ajax_menu');

function get_ajax_menu() {
global $wp_query;

echo "Категория меню: " .$category_id = $_GET['category_id']."<br>";

echo "<div class='menu_tags table_main'>
<div class='row_main'>  
  <div class='cell_main'>";
         the_post();
         the_content();
echo "</div>
</div>
</div>";
exit;
}
```

Файл `ajax`-запроса:

```
$(".menu_manager .menu_category a").click( function() {
var category_id = $(this).attr('data-item');
$.ajax ({
  url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "html",
  data: "action=ajax_menu&category_id="+category_id,
  success: function (html){
    $(".main").html(html);
  }
})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
the_post()
the_content()
```

Используются внутри лупа.
Я б рекомендовал также использывать `POST` запрос. 
В функциях:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_menu', 'get_ajax_menu');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_menu', 'get_ajax_menu');

function get_ajax_menu() {
    global $wp_query;
    $cat = (isset($_POST['category_id'])) ? $_POST['category_id'] : 0;
    echo 'Категория меню: '.$cat.PHP_EOL;
    // Формирование параметров запроса
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 10, //Количество постов для вывода
        'cat' => $cat
    );
    //запрос к БД и цикл вывода
    $get_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ($get_posts->have_posts()) :
        echo '  <div class=\'menu_tags table_main\'>
                <div class=\'row_main\'>';
        while ($get_posts->have_posts()) : $get_posts->the_post();
            echo '<div class=\'cell_main\'>';
            the_content();
            echo '</div>';
        endwhile;
        echo '</div></div>';
     endif;
     wp_die();
}
```

А также, js код:

```
    $(".menu_manager .menu_category a").click( function() {
        var data = {
                    action: 'ajax_menu',
                    category_id: $(this).attr('data-item');
                    };
        $.post( ajaxurl, data, function(response) 
        {
            $(".main").html(response);
        });

})
```